# No confirmation dialog when retracting a flag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, confirmation, retracted-flags

I just retracted a flag that I cast on an answer and noticed that clicking the "Retract" button caused immediate retraction of the flag, without any confirmation dialog.

We have such confirmation for all other actions that involve a single button click (deleting comments, deleting posts, etc., pretty sure that retracting a close vote also have confirmation).

Can a confirmation dialog please be added when we click the Retract Flag button?

Comment: Isn't the flag dialog itself a confirmation here? You don't get an extra pop-up after that dialog when *leaving* a flag...

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to ask this question? [Maybe move it to the Recycle Bin?](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/ximage82.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.5E6EeMEA-b.png) :)

Comment: @gnat heh, kind of blonde moment as I thought retracting a close vote did give confirmation. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flag dialog when adding a flag:

[image: select the flag, then hit "Flag..." to confirm]

The flag dialog when retracting a flag:

[image: Confirm retraction of already-raised flag by hitting "Retract Flag"]

IOW, the flag dialog itself is the confirmation both for raising and retracting - it presents you with the information on the current state of your flag, and requires another click to raise or retract the flag.

Comment: The problem with this is that once you have retracted a flag, **you can't flag again.** I retracted a flag just now because I realized that in the specific case, flagging as a duplicate would have been better (as in provided more information to the community) than flagging as off-topic, and now I can't flag the post as anything (because I can't flag the same post twice). Compare this to the confirmation when you retract an uptick on a comment, which explicitly says that "you won't be able to upvote again". Could you at least consider adding a notice "if you retract, you can't flag again"?